# Как сделать массив double nullable

Tags: c#, массивы, null

Как сделать массив `double` nullable?

```
double[,] numbersArray = new double[3, 3];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 вариант:

```
double?[,] numbersArray = new double?[3, 3];
```

2 вариант:

```
Nullable<double>[,] numbersArray2 = new Nullable<double>[3, 3];
```

можно даже так:

```
Nullable<double>[,] numbersArray3 = new double?[3, 3];
```

И вот так:

```
double?[,] numbersArray4 = new Nullable<double>[3, 3];
```

Выбирайте!

Comment: Тогда уже логично и четвёртый вариант?

Comment: @VladD, Сию секунду)

Comment: Воооот! Полная симметрия!

Comment: Ну а чем они различаются?

Comment: @Александр, ничем, вариант с '?' упрощенная запись Nullable<T>

Comment: Тогда еще 2 варианта с `var` ;)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, остановитесь)

Comment: @Александр собственно, только в обозначении. Скомпилированный код во всех случаях одинаковый. Но как я знаю, предпочтение отдают `double?`

Answer (score 2):

Не удержусь от того, чтобы не добавить ещё один редко используемый метод: создание с одновременной инициализацией. Обратите внимание, `new` не используется.

```
double?[,] numbersArray5 = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };
```

и соответственно

```
Nullable<double>[,] numbersArray6 = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };
```